# How to use right word in right way with sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I am learning vocabulary as I am not a native speaker , I just search word `intrinsic` and found its meaning as `Belonging to a thing by its very nature` . But I don't know how we can use it correctly Like if my brother's nature is same like me so Can I say

`My brother's intrinsic like me`

OR

If we have two toy of car's and their behaviour same like moving with the remote so we can use it like

```
These toys are intrinsic with each other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the meaning of the word *intrinsic* the way you want to use is given in a better way on [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/intrinsic). I'm not a native speaker and thus at times, get trapped to use the word correctly in a sentence though I knew the word. The best way to overcome this is check on reputed sites (dictionaries?) how the sentences use the word in concern.

OALD gives an example there.

> ***intrinsic to something*** - Small local shops are intrinsic to the town's character

And, I think it fulfills your purpose.

Since you are talking about the *nature*,

> My brother is *intrinsic to* my nature.

However, I'd tell that second sentence in some other way. That's because your sentence looks strange to *me.*

> These toy cars function in same way.